# Does the Talmud talk about Autism?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, psych-mentalhealth, shoteh-mental-incompetent

BH

Does the Talmud Mention anything about Autism or the Spectrum of any of the symptoms of Autism?

Answer (score 1):

There is a halachic concept called an "Eastonis". It's basically a fussy person who can't deal with discomfort and gets exceptions from rabinnical stringencies when they bother him. The concept may also describe an OCD person.

See here:

[Talmudic concept of a sensitive individual--"istus?"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105570/talmudic-concept-of-a-sensitive-individual-istus)

Comment: אסטניס refers to a person with general fragility, not someone with sensory overload due to autism. This answer is not correct. See here for a translation of the word. https://www.morfix.co.il/en/%D7%90%D7%A1%D7%98%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A1

Comment: Eastonis does characterize some autistic behaviors. The answer is correct as it is the closest halachic concept to an autistic person.